# CSS FlexBox - stretch child but not parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a DIV that has a child div which is displayed on hover.

Because I am using "visibility: hidden" the div is not stretched when the hidden div is displayed and nor does his parent.

What I am trying to achieve:

1. The parent div should NOT stretch.
2. The child div (Containing the hidden div) should stretch.

Is that possible using CSS without defining a static width?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMzXzx

```
<style>

.page{
flex-direction:column;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}

.parent{
margin-top:4px;
padding:5px;
flex-direction:column;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
border:2px solid black;
}

.child{
margin-top:4px;
border:1px solid black;
flex-direction:column;
display:flex;
}

.child-sub{
visibility:hidden;
}

.child:hover .child-sub{
visibility:visible;
}
</style>


<div class="page">
I want the parent div to NOT resize on child hover but the child div should resize. Can this be done with CSS?
    <div class="parent">Parent-div
        <div class="child">Child-div (Hover to display hidden div)
            <div class="child-sub">Sub-menu</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see what you're trying to do with your example: the element whose visibility you are toggling is already smaller than the child element, so it will not affect the layout at all.

Comment: How do you want the child div to behave? How is it supposed to resize? Shrink?

Comment: It's not affecting because the visibility is set to hidden. If visibility would have been "display:none" it would have stretchered both child and parent divs. See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brOPXM

Comment: The child div should stretch like done in this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brOPXM. But the parent SHOULD NOT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make that work responsive, I suggest you move the `child-sub` outside the `child` and then, in combination with `visibility: hidden/visible`, a negative top margin (to hide the `child`'s border), you can accomplish that visually.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLBVzp)

Stack snippet

```css
.page {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent {
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.child-sub {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-color: white;
  margin-top: -1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.child-sub:hover,
.child:hover+.child-sub {
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  I want the parent div to NOT resize on child hover but the child div should resize. Can this be done with CSS?
  <div class="parent">Parent-div
    <div class="child">Child-div (Hover to display hidden div)
    </div>
    <div class="child-sub">Sub-menu</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that the child div exceeds the border of it's parent. I want the Parent not to stretch on hover, but when the page loads it needs to be wide enough to contain also the sub menu.

Comment: @DavidSomekh First, you say _parent should not stretch on hover_, and now you say _The problem with your solution is that the child div exceeds the border of it's parent._, which for me is contradictory. Post a non-hover and a hover image/drawing showing exactly what it should look like. ... Second, _but when the page loads it needs to be wide enough to contain also the sub menu._, does hat mean that the submenu can be wider than the child and/or parent, and that they should adjust their/its width based on the content in the submenu?

Comment: @DavidSomekh Also, when you say _parent should not stretch_, do you mean its border only, or do you also mean if there are content rendered after the parent, it should not be push down, but be overlapped by the submenu?

Comment: here is how it should look (Without defining a static height like the example): https://codepen.io/dsomekh/pen/dzrMdK - As you can see, the child is stretching but the parent is not. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidSomekh Updated my answer

Comment: LGSon, good work! One problem though: The sub-menu should be clickable. But with your solution, if I try to click it I am no longer hovering the "child" div and then it is not displayed. Any way around that?

Comment: @DavidSomekh Updated the answer again.